# PL/SQL : subprogram or cursor 'P_STATUS_UPDATE' is declared in a package specification and must be defined in the package body

Tags: plsql, package, specifications

Here's my package specification

```
create package fs_atm_trans_pkg
is
procedure p_status_update;

function f_get_status(i_customer_id number, i_pin_num number, i_account_balance number, v_customer_id number, v_pin_num number, v_account_balance number) 
return varchar;

end fs_atm_trans_pkg;
```

And the package specification is created successfully.

Here's my package body.

```
create package body fs_atm_trans_pkg is

procedure p_status_update(v_result_cust varchar2, v_balance_nr number,i_trans_id number) is 
   cursor cur_tran is --select all data from transactions along with stored customer data, LEFT JOIN
    select * from bank_trans t left join bank_customer c
        on t.cust_id = c.customer_id left join bank_acct a on c.customer_pk=a.customer_fk
        for update of status;
        v_result_cust varchar2(50);
begin 
  for each_tra in cur_tran loop
  v_result_cust:= f_get_status(each_tra.CUST_ID,
                                        each_tra.PIN_NUMBER,
                                        each_tra.ACCT_BALANCE,
                                        each_tra.customer_id,
                                        each_tra.pin_num,
                                        each_tra.account_balance);

  if v_result_cust='Successful' then
        update bank_trans set bank_trans.acct_balance = v_balance_nr - bank_trans.acct_balance 
        where i_trans_id = bank_trans.transaction_id;
        update bank_trans set status = v_result_cust
        where i_trans_id = bank_trans.transaction_id;
        else 
        update bank_trans set status = v_result_cust
        where i_trans_id = bank_trans.transaction_id;
        end if;
  end loop;
end;

FUNCTION f_get_status(i_customer_id number, 
                                        i_pin_num number, 
                                        i_account_balance number,
                                        v_customer_id number, 
                                        v_pin_num number, 
                                        v_account_balance number) 
    RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    r_trans_status varchar2(100); 

    BEGIN
        IF i_customer_id = v_customer_id then
                if i_pin_num = v_pin_num then
                    if i_account_balance < v_account_balance
                    then r_trans_status := 'Successful';
                    else r_trans_status := 'Insufficient Fund';
                    end if;
                else r_trans_status := 'Invalid Pin';
                end if;
        else r_trans_status := 'Invalid ID';
        END IF;
    RETURN r_trans_status; 
    end;


end fs_atm_trans_pkg;
```

When I run my package body, it gave out errors as follows:

> Duplicate fields in RECORD,TABLE or argument list are not permitted
>
> Subprogram or cursor 'P_STATUS_UPDATE' is declared in a package specification and must be defined in the package body
>
> Subprogram or cursor 'F_GET_STATUS' is declared in a package specification and must be defined in the package body

What should I do to fix these three errors? 
I would appreciate if everyone could hep.

Answer (score 1):

The package specification has:

```
procedure p_status_update;
```

while in the body it's

```
procedure p_status_update(v_result_cust varchar2, v_balance_nr number,i_trans_id number)
```

The two need to match.

The issue with `f_get_status` is it's declared in the package specification as returning `varchar` but in the body as `varchar2`.

Cursor `cur_tran` seems to have the same column name more than once. It would be a good idea to list out the columns you want explicitly, rather than using `select *`.

By the way, parameter naming is up to you but normally `v_` is used for **v**ariables, so giving parameters names like `v_customer_id` might cause confusion later on.